# Creating Scoring Matrix

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column

I have a scoring matrix which I use in excel consisting of 5 categories each scored by Impact & Likelihood using a look up, then multiplied. The total from each category is summed to provide a Final Score. Can this be done in SharePoint 2013 easily and if so how:

Example:

**Category 1**

Impact: Serve = 4

likelihood: Happening = 5

Total Cat 1 = Impact multiplied by likelihood

**Category 2**

Impact: Major = 3

likelihood: Probable = 3

Total Cat 2 = Impact multiplied by likelihood